# Xdebug don't show trace and dump

Tags: xdebug

Why xdebug don't show error trace and var_dump (only php standatr error output)? But debuging is working.

I am working n Mac OS Lion.

Here is my configuration:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so
; Remote settings
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000

; General
xdebug.show_local_vars=On
xdebug.dump.SERVER=HTTP_HOST, SERVER_NAME
xdebug.dump_globals=On
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.auto_trace=off
xdebug.collect_includes=on
xdebug.collect_return=off
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.manual_url=http://www.php.net
xdebug.show_mem_delta=1
xdebug.max_nesting_level=100
xdebug.idekey=xdebug

; Trace options
xdebug.trace_format=0
xdebug.trace_output_dir=/tmp/xdebug/trace
xdebug.trace_options=0
xdebug.trace_output_name=tracelog

; Profiling
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp/xdebug/debug
xdebug.profiler_output_name=scriptprofile.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have html_errors set to on (1) in php.ini as well. This is for some odd reason turned off by default in PHP 5.3. In PHP 5.4, the default is on (1) again.